# What role does this 'preposition plus relative pronoun' take?

Tags: prepositions, relative-pronouns

> While the direction was being executed, the lady consulted moved
>   slowly up the room.  I suppose I have a considerable organ of
>   veneration, for I retain yet the sense of admiring awe **with which** my
>   eyes traced her steps. (Jane Eyre)

Does ‘with which’ plays a role of adverb phrase in its relative clause, and the relative clause (with which my eyes trace her steps) make an adjective clause for the NP before of it?

Comment: I do not understand the question, nor why it could possibly matter. Why do you want to know this strange structural stuff anyway?

Comment: @tchrist, Because English structures are quite different from my mother tongue, Korean. So if I can’t parse them, that exactly mean I don’t understand what they are saying. Why? For understanding what they are saying! If you were to learn Korean or Japanese, you could know what I say.

Comment: **<comments removed>** Comments should be used to ask for clarifications or make suggestions on how to improve the post. Please refrain from turning comments into miniature chat room and discussion forums. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it.

The basic form of the final clause, in traditional grammar, is:

> [<sub>Subject</sub>My eyes] [<sub>Verb</sub>traced] [<sub>Direct Object</sub>her steps] [<sub>prepositional phrase</sub>[<sub>preposition</sub>with] [<sub>object</sub>a sense of admiring awe].

The prepositional phrase (which has another prepositional phrase 'embedded') modifies the verb *traced*.

In order to focus on *sense* as the object of the previous verb *retain*, we

1. move *the sense &c* to the object position ...

   > I retain yet [*the sense of admiring awe*]
2. replace *the sense &c* with the relative pronoun *which* (which is therefore now the object of the preposition *with*), and ‘front’ it ...

   > **which** [my eyes traced her steps with.]
3. then, since *with* is a true preposition, not a component of a phrasal verb, we move it to its natural position ahead of its object.

   > *with* which [my eyes traced her steps]

Note that step 3 can only be carried out with a WH- relative, not with *that*. The technical term for it is [‘pied piping’](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied_piping#Pied-piping), after the old German story of the [‘Pied Piper of Hamelin’](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied_Piper_of_Hamelin), the subject of a charming [poem by Robert Browning](http://www.indiana.edu/%7Elibrcsd/etext/piper/).